# Julia Find Index of Iterative Value

Tags: indexing, iterator, julia, built-in

Im trying to find the index of an item in an array within a for loop that steps from item to item in the Array. Is there a built in function that allows me to do this?

```
dim = 3
length = 10

arrayTuple = fill!(Array(Int64, dim),length)
# [10,10,10]

Arr = fill!(Array(Int64,tuple(arrayTuple...)),1)

for item in Arr
    #print the index of node into array here
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.enumerate):

```
julia> for (i, item) in enumerate(Arr[1:5])
           println(i, " ", item)
       end
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
```

If you want the multidimensional version, you could use [`eachindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachindex) instead:

```
julia> for i in eachindex(a)
           println(i, " ", a[i])
       end
Base.IteratorsMD.CartesianIndex_3(1,1,1) 1.0
Base.IteratorsMD.CartesianIndex_3(2,1,1) 1.0
Base.IteratorsMD.CartesianIndex_3(3,1,1) 1.0
Base.IteratorsMD.CartesianIndex_3(1,2,1) 1.0
[... and so on]
```

Comment: enumerate does not provide proper indexes for arrays above one dimension. Can enumerate provide multidimensional indexes?

Comment: @JamesBeezho: ah, no, but `eachindex` can.

Comment: The above comment answers my question; however, it is worth noting that eachindex() is only available in julia 0.4.0, an unstable release.